# How can I simulate hitting enter or clicking outside a filled form to send data to server?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a Rails app and and a form using React. When a user fills a field, the data is sent the moment they press enter on their keyboard or when they clicks anywhere else on the page.

I'm testing this feature and I'm trying to reproduce the same behavior but what I've tried so far do not work...

I'm using Capybara with Rspec to test features. I've already tried those following:

- `find('.class').set("text").native.send_keys(:return)`
- `find('.class').set("text\n")`
- `page.execute_script("document.querySelector('.some_other_div').click()")`
- `fill_in "name", with: "text\n"`

I have no problem to fill the form but I am not able to send it to the server...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you used a `binding.pry` to try and t/s this while testing?

Comment: I use js:true + sleep within my code to open a selenium chrome page and have a look at it: the field is well filled but the mouse cursor stays within it. Consequence: the data is not pushed to the server because no enter key or click outside the div is triggered